# How to hide joint axis in Rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you hide the joint axis in Rviz, or at least make them translucent or smaller so they don't hide your model?

I have a model consisting of a box with a single thin "leg", but the joint axis indicators for the leg are so big, they're obscuring the leg.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myrobot"
    xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <!-- Included URDF/XACRO Files -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find myrobot_description)/urdf/materials.urdf.xacro" />
    
    <!-- width in meters -->
    <property name="torso_x_size" value="0.1" />
    
    <!-- length in meters -->
    <property name="torso_y_size" value="0.205" />
    
    <!-- height in meters -->
    <property name="torso_z_size" value="0.03" />
    
    <!-- torso mass (not including legs) in kg -->
    <property name="torso_mass" value="0.920" />
    
    <!-- mass of a single upper leg piece in kg -->
    <property name="upper_leg_mass" value="0.010" />
    
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${torso_x_size} ${torso_y_size} ${torso_z_size}" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="red"/>
        </visual>
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="${torso_mass}"/>
    </link>
    <xacro:macro name="leg" params="name reflect_x reflect_y">
        <link name="${name}">
            <visual>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.003 0.04 0.005" />
                </geometry>
                <origin xyz="0 0.04 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <material name="blue" />
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.003 0.04 0.005" />
                </geometry>
                <origin xyz="0 0.04 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            </collision>
            <xacro:default_inertial mass="${upper_leg_mass}"/>
        </link>
        <joint name="torso_to_${name}" type="fixed">
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="${name}"/>
            <origin xyz="${torso_x_size/2*reflect_x} ${torso_y_size/2*reflect_y} 0" />
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>
    <xacro:leg name="front_right_leg" reflect_x="1" reflect_y="1" />
</robot>
```

[image: image description]

The default leg position puts it right where the green cylinder is, which, as you can see, completely obscures it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207964/how-to-hide-joint-axis-in-rviz/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The axes you're trying to hide are part of the TF display.

You can either disable the TF display completely, or expand the TF display properties and adjust the settings. It has a number of different options for changing the axes size, hiding and showing axes and the connecting arrows, adjusting the transparency, and and hiding and showing axes for individual frames.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-27**:
Thanks. Digging into the urdf_tutorial's code, apparently that's all saved in a *.rviz file, so I can just copy that into my own package and customize the settings so I don't have to manually change them every time I load Rviz.

**Comment by [FBaralli](https://answers.ros.org/users/27396/fbaralli/) on 2016-07-05**:
Hi,
I'm using RViz 1.11.10 from Jade and I'm editing the config file .rviz to hide some of the axes, however everytime I restart RViz all the axes are visible. All the other settings are maintained.
Any idea?

Francesco